# IntelliJ .proto support

Tags: java, intellij-idea, protocol-buffers

I have IntelliJIdea 12 Ultimate edition (personal license). I have a `.proto` file that was being opened as a text file because IntelliJ could not recognize the `.proto` extension. I looked into the plugin repo for IntelliJ and found "Google Protobuf Buffers support" (More info about the plugin [here](https://github.com/nnmatveev/idea-plugin-protobuf)). I installed it and restarted IntelliJ but the `.proto` files are still being recognized at text files. There is no IntelliSense.

Has anyone successfully installed and used this plugin? Could you please share how you made it to work? Also, if you used some other way then please share that as well. My goal is to add IntelliSense to IntelliJ for `.proto` files.

Comment: I just had a try and it worked well. Could you please check "File Types" in IDEA? Open "Settings" -> type "file types" to search "File Types" setting -> Check "Protocol Buffers file" in "Recognized File Types", make sure "*.proto" is in "Registered Patterns".

Comment: @lhuang thanks for the reply. For some reason, IntelliJ started recognizing the proto file correctly after completely quitting IntelliJ and restarting it. I swear I remember quiting and restarting IntelliJ after plugin installation but hey, works now !

Answer (score 9):

**You can get .proto support if you follow this steps:**

1. Install a plugin [Protobuf Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8277-protobuf-support/)

(You can install throught Intellij File>Settings>Plugins>Search for Protobuf Support in the marketplace search)

2. Try to open some .proto file, if everythings works you are **done**
3. If Intellij doesn't recognise the file go to File>Settings>Editor>File Types.
4. Under recognized file types find "ProtoBuf"
5. Click on it and then press the plus/add button to add a registred pattern
6. Pattern should be ***.proto**  (don't forget the star before .proto)
7. Restart Intellij just to be sure

P.S : People already answered in the comments, but at first I didn't notice so I decided to write an answer, it might help somone :)